# Continuous Click on image button without lifting finger in android

Tags: android

So in my app i have this 4x4 imagebutton. I don't have any experience in android programming since this is my very first app. As in the picture, I am forming a word "BIT" (displayed in texview). My question is how can i click these imagebuttons to form words WITHOUT lifting the finger? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. I would love if you'll also help me with the codes.

[image]

Heres the code i am using :

**MainActivity.java**

```js
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     DBAdapter dbHelper;
     EditText words, scores, search;
     ImageView show_addWord;
     TextView score, tv2, tv3;
     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;
     int z = 0;
     protected static final String TAG = null;
     String generatedString = " ";
     AutoCompleteTextView text;
     TextView timer;
     ImageView searchWord;
     ImageView bomb, searchword, lineone;
     ImageButton image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8,
     image9, image10, image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16;
     ListView wordList;
     private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
     private boolean timeHasStarted = false;
     
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            
            dbHelper =new DBAdapter(this);
            search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
            words = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
            scores = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edScore);
            show_addWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_addWord);
                    
            bomb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bomb);
            searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
            wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
            image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1); ...
      image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);

      timer = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
      timer.setText("00:00:30");
      countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000,1000);
      
      final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
      
      final ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1); ..
      final ImageButton image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);  
      
       
      final int[] myPics = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,  ... };
      
      //randomize image
            
      bomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           //new set of tile

       }
      });
      
      
      
      // start countdowntimer, display text in textview according to image
      OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                    
                    if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
                        Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                        generatedString=generatedString+"a"; //[PLACEE RESPACTIVE CHARACTEER HERE]
                        text.setText(generatedString);
               
                if (!timeHasStarted) {
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    timeHasStarted = true;
                    }
       }
       
      };

      
      
      image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);

        }

 public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
      public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
       super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
      }

@Override
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       long millis = millisUntilFinished;  
                String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));  
                System.out.println(hms);  
                timer.setText(hms);  
       
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
       timer.setText("Time's Up!");
      }
     }

// searching word, displaying score on score textview and populating listview via textview data        
        
        
        private int optionTxtView = 0  ;
        public void viewWord(View view)
        {
         score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
         tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            
            searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
            wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
            text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
            wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
         
         String s1= search.getText().toString();
            String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);

            score.setText(s2);
         tv2.setText(s2);
         tv3.setText(s2);
         

        /*  // Display score on first click in txtview, second click in txtview 2 ...
          // NOT WORKING !!!!!!!!
          if(optionTxtView == 0){
                //display the score on textview1
               tv2.setText(s2);
               optionTxtView = 1;
          }else{
                //display the score on textview2    
                tv3.setText(s2);
              optionTxtView = 0;
          }
        */ 
         
         
         
         
         
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
            wordList.setAdapter(adapter);    
         adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            text.setText("");
          
        }
     
//adding 2 textview
        public void add (){
         x = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString());
            y = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString());
            z = x + y;
            score.setText(Double.toString(z));
        }
        
    }
```

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

you want to click the image without lifting a finger? the user does that, so tell em to do that..(lafing out loud).. actually im joking.

all you have to do is call the imagebutton object and call a loop for the number of letters you are going to type to form a word and call ..`performClick()`-() on the preferred imagebutton.. get it now??

so an example.. i want to spell **Lab Ley**.. i will need to click on 7 diff imagebuttons so

```
for(int i = 0; i<7; ++i){ // i++ any way goes
   ImageButton.performClick(); // imagebutton is the respective lettered imagebutton you want
}
```

Comment: Where in my java part shoul I put this one? and can i change it to something like i = 16? because I have 16 imagebuttons @Elltz

Comment: No. no..dont confuse yourself, i am answering your questions based on your questions specificallyokay.. you have a whole problem to solve- that's your app, but i am solving one part of it for you, that's answering your question specifically, and i didnt read your codes, i answered based on the question, because you didn't specify if  what you wanted to spell was know or unknown.. get me now? but after going through all your questions i see what you want to do, so i'd say gridview, then implement onhoverlistener for the items..thats if your app support api 14+@LabLey

Comment: so this answer is if you want to spell lab Ley programmatically-from your question. get me now@LabLey

Comment: The words are unknown because the user needs to find words himself. 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
:)

Comment: Whats the difference between onHover and OnTouch? Which one is much better? @Elltz